# How to made the height of the cardview/constaint layout have the same as width

Tags: android, constraints, android-constraintlayout, android-xml

apologies if I am confusing it, in a constraint layout I have two card views which are equally spread out width wise based on constraints start and end.

The text thats going in those constraint layout text view is fixed size.

What I want to achieve is, the height of both card views to be same as the width of them.

we know that width of both will be the same cuz of constraints

but how can i set the height to be the same as with width.

basically want them to be two squares next to each other without setting hardcoded value.

Thanks in advance
R

```
 <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cvOne"
            style="@style/Tile"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cvTwo"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cvChargeScheduleLayout">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/clOne"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/white_screen_bg"
                android:clipChildren="false"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:padding="8dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    
                    android:text="this is a fixed text"/>
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cvTwo"
            style="@style/Tile"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cvOne"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cvChargeScheduleLayout">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/clTwo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/white_screen_bg"
                android:clipChildren="false"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:padding="8dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="this is a fixed text a bit longer....."/>
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. (Pardon the colors. They are there just to highlight the *CardViews*.)

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cvOne"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cvTwo"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cvChargeScheduleLayout">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/clOne"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:text="this is a fixed text" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cvTwo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cvOne"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cvChargeScheduleLayout">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/clTwo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="this is a fixed text a bit longer....." />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

See [Ratio](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#ratio) in the documentation.

> You can also define one dimension of a widget as a ratio of the other one. In order to do that, you need to have at least one constrained dimension be set to 0dp (i.e., MATCH_CONSTRAINT), and set the attribute layout_constraintDimensionRatio to a given ratio...

[image]

Comment: Hello thanks for replying, adding the width wrap content, made one longer and one shorter, I want them to take equal width so they have same width and height to be the same as width

Comment: @BRDroid You did say two side-by-side. See the updated answer.